# How to use JS function in SASS

Tags: javascript, sass

i'm using this website to calculate my prefered value for clamp.
[CodeSandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/clamp-linear-intepolation-based-on-viewport-width-builder-xgkft)

```
clamp(min, prefered, max)
```

Values in form (min/max viewport width and 1rem=) will be static for project.

I don't want to go to website over and over. So, should i use any sass function like

```
font-size: myClamp($min-fontsize, $max-fontsize)
```

send this variables to my function.js file where will be function from the website

```
  const minWidth = minWidthPx / pixelsPerRem;
  const maxWidth = maxWidthPx / pixelsPerRem;

  const slope = (maxFontSize - minFontSize) / (maxWidth - minWidth);
  const yAxisIntersection = -minWidth * slope + minFontSize;

  const myClamp = `font-size: clamp(${minFontSize}rem, ${yAxisIntersection.toFixed
  (4)}rem + ${(slope * 100).toFixed(4)}vw, ${maxFontSize}rem);`;
```

and then return myClamp const to my sass file? And its gonna look like

```
font-size: clamp(1rem, -0.8750rem + 8.3333vw, 3.5rem);
```

I'm using something similar for px to rem. But this is just between two scss files

```
_function.scss
/* Px to Rem */

$browser-context: 16; // Default

@function r($pixels, $context: $browser-context) {
  @return #{$pixels/$context}rem;
}

style.scss

font-size: r(20); // in pixels
```

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Please edit your post title into a clear, specific question rather than a pseudo-code snippet.

Comment: You cannot use a JS function in SASS. But you can define a [function in SASS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function) that does the calculations and returns what you need via string interpolation.